# Sass: Mix rgba(white,0.5) and solid background color

Tags: css, colors, sass, background-color

Need to calculate a final color for a font. In PSD the opacity of a font is `50%`, color is `#fff`, background color is `#7a4eb7`. The result accordingly Photoshop should be `#c4b5dd`.

I guess there is no need in transparent color if background is always the same.

Can it be achieved with `Sass`?

Found an article on this topic but can't make it working:
http://thesassway.com/intermediate/mixins-for-semi-transparent-colors

Comment: Show your attempts, "doesn't work" doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: Well, I used the mixin called `alpha-background-color` from the article and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Just tried another one `alpha-attribute` with small modifications and it did worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just resolved my question using second mixin from the article:

```
@mixin alpha-attribute($attribute, $color, $background) {
  $percent: alpha($color) * 100%;
  $opaque: opacify($color, 1);
  $solid-color: mix($opaque, $background, $percent);
  #{$attribute}: $solid-color;
}
```

Then you can use it as following:

```
// Mix font color rgba($white,0.5) and solid background
.text {
    @include alpha-attribute('color', rgba($white, 0.5), $studio);
}
```